# Qt: Use QAudioRecorder to return buffer

Tags: qt, qaudiorecorder

I want to use `QAudioRecorder` to record an audio and save as a file and display the `filepath` to the user. I had tried using the the example from Qt but there's no feed on the buffer value when I tested it on Android. It works on my Desktop though. Below are part of my codes:

```
AudioRecord::AudioRecord(QWidget *parent)
{
    audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder(this);
    probe = new QAudioProbe;

    connect(probe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)),
            this, SLOT(processBuffer(QAudioBuffer)));
    probe->setSource(audioRecorder);
}

void AudioRecord::processBuffer(const QAudioBuffer& buffer)
{
    qDebug()<<"Testing Successful";
}
```

The `processBuffer` function does not seems to be called. What should I do to get the buffer value work? Is there any other way around?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @garfbradaz thanks. I made some changes on my question.

Comment: @PhilipMoh, i have same question, did you get any clue for this question?